# Can you place if immediately after for in Java?

Tags: java

Eclipse lets me write some code like this, and doesn't show any errors:

```
for (SomeClass c : listOfSomeClass) if (c.someBoolean) {
    // actions to take if someBoolean is true
}
```

Will this behave as expected, or is this not valid Java?

Comment: This is valid statement

Comment: Most of the time, tools like CheckStyle, PMD or anything compliant with Sonar will advise you to always use {}. As the most important thing is clarity and simplicity, don't hesitate to follow this advice ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's valid.  The `if` will get repeated as many times as there are elements of `listOfSomeClass`.  But that doesn't mean that writing Java like this is a good idea.  Please don't ever do this.

You could even write something like

```
for (SomeClass c : listOfSomeClass) if (c.someBoolean) System.out.println(c);
```

if you were feeling particularly perverse.

However, when you write code, it's important to write code that another programmer can easily read, understand, and modify if necessary.  Once a software system is in production, you can be fairly sure that changes will be required in it at some point in the future.  What you can't be sure of is exactly what those changes will be.

So a good programmer, a professional programmer, writes his/her code in a way that makes it as easy as possible to change; and that means as easy as possible to understand.  Now we professional programmers get used to seeing code laid out in certain ways.  Curly braces used with `for` and with `if`, whether they're actually required or not.  Consistent indentation.  Intuitive use of variable names, and so on.  Anything slightly unusual slows us down.

I don't want to be scratching my head, trying to work out how code works.  I don't want to have to THINK about which lines are part of the `for` loop, or the `if` branch.  I want code that tells me what it does, the first time I cast my eyes upon it.  So, if you are EVER on the same team as me - or on the same team as any programmer who vaguely resembles me - then for the love of all that is good in this world, write this loop exactly like this.

```
for (SomeClass element : listOfSomeClass) {
    if (element.shouldBePrinted()) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you mind explaining why? I'm still learning Java. A link to a reference explaining why would be OK too.

Comment: Do you mean why it's valid?  Or why you shouldn't do it?

Comment: @John you should not do it becasue it makes your code hard to read. Unreadable code = crap no matter if it actually is great code that works fine.

Comment: @John please see my answer and let me know whether your queries solved or not

Answer (score 5):

It works fine, but the formatting it likely to be confusing. Even you are not sure of what it will do.  I suggest you use the standard formatter in eclipse to produce something like

```
for (SomeClass c : listOfSomeClass) 
    if (c.someBoolean) {
        // actions to take if someBoolean is true
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

yes it can be done,the if loop

```
if (c.someBoolean) {
    // actions to take if someBoolean is true
}
```

will be executed multiple times

What ever is there immediately after the for loop will be executed.
for example

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
System.out.println("welcome");
```

is same as

```
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    System.out.println("welcome");
}
```

So it will print welcome 10 times.

But this example

f

```
or(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    System.out.println("welcome");
    System.out.println("outside");
```

will print welcome 10 times and outside one time.
The above code is similar to

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    System.out.println("welcome");
}
    System.out.println("outside");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is valid Java code and this is the same as:

```
for (SomeClass c : listOfSomeClass) {
    if (c.someBoolean) {
        // actions to take if someBoolean is true
    } 
}
```

Actually Java allows you to write a one-line statement after the for loop condition. Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.println(i);
```

Note that this style is usually discouraged since it can lead to misunderstanding of what the code does.

Answer (score 2):

Informally, the `for` construct has this grammar:

`for (...)` *statement*

Normally, *statement* will take the form `{`set of instructions each separated by;`}` but, of course, it's possible to omit the braces for a single statement.

Since `if (`...`){ }` *is* a statement, **your code is valid**.

But it is obscure though: at the very least adhere to an established convention and start the `if` on the next line with an extra level of indentation. I *always* use braces when writing a `for` loop but that's a personal choice and plenty of well-respected coders don't.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid. If you do not use curly braces "{", then only the first command is executed. For example, if you had another command after the "if" block, it would not be a part of your "for" loop.

Example:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    System.out.println(i);
System.out.println("Hello");
```

will print:

```
0
1
2
Hello
```

and **not**:

```
0
Hello
1
Hello
2
Hello
```

The second output would be printed if you had the following code:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

However, it is recommended to use the block statement.

Answer (score 0):

if you want multiple line execution in loop then you write it like this

```
for (SomeClass c : listOfSomeClass)  
{
    //multiple lines to be executed
    System.out.println("print this awesome line");
}
```

now if you want only a sinle code line to execute accoring to the loop then you write it like this

```
for (SomeClass c : listOfSomeClass)  
    System.out.println("print this awesome line");
```

now this line can be any valid line of code
thus if condition is also allowed

```
if(awesomeCondition)
{
    System.out.println("print this awesome line in side legendary if condition");
}
```

thus your final code is

```
for (SomeClass c : listOfSomeClass)  
if(awesomeCondition)
{
    System.out.println("print this awesome line in side legendary if condition");
}
```

which is equally compatible to

```
for (SomeClass c : listOfSomeClass)  
{
    if(awesomeCondition)
    {
        System.out.println("print this awesome line in side legendary if condition");
    }// end of IF block
}// end of for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Java Language Specification of [`for`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14) you'll see (for the [enhanced for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)):

> ```
> for ( FormalParameter : Expression ) Statement
> ```

And the definition of [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) is:

> ```
> Statement:
>     StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
>     ...
>     IfThenStatement
>     ...
>
> StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement:
>     Block
>     ...
> ```

(I have left out some of the definitions)

In other words the statement in your question is equivalent to `for ( FormalParameter : Expression ) Statement` where `Statement`: `IfThenStatement`.

Now in general it is advisable to use a `Block` instead, or at least indent for better readability. Your statement is equivalent to:

```
for (SomeClass c : listOfSomeClass) 
    if (c.someBoolean) {
        // actions to take if someBoolean is true
    }
```

Or better yet:

```
for (SomeClass c : listOfSomeClass) {
    if (c.someBoolean) {
        // actions to take if someBoolean is true
    }
}
```